# Why the two demo of Stanford CoreNLP gives different results?

Tags: stanford-nlp

```
Cruella De Vil is a fur-loving maniac in which Disney movie?
```

this sentence gives different results on http://corenlp.run/ and http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process. Is there some setting that causes the difference? I am able to get the same results using the latest downloaded model as with http://corenlp.run/ but http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process seems to be more accurate for this specific statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older demo is not really supported any more.  We are generally using http://corenlp.run .  In fact, we may shut down the older demos.

The two demos use different models.  If you want to try to match the results of the older demo, you'll probably have to search through the history of releases and look at older NER models for releases such as 3.5.1 etc...Ultimately we believe the current model is better, but in individual cases an older model can perform better.